# Setup secured Jenkins master with docker

Tags: ssl, jenkins, https, amazon-ec2, docker

I would like to set up a secured Jenkins master server on ec2 with docker.
I'm using standard jenkins docker file from here: https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/jenkins/

By default it opens an unsecured 8080 http port. However I want it to use a standard 443 port with https (at first I want to use self-signed ssl certificate).

I researched in this topic a little bit and found several possible solution. I'm not really experienced with docker so I still couldn't find a simple one I can use or implement. Here are some options I found:

- Use standard jenkins docker on 8080 but configure a secured apache or nginx server on my ec2 instance that will redirect the trafic. I don't like this because the server will be outside the docker so I can not keep it in the version control
- Somehow modify the jenkins docker file to start jenkins with a https configured according to https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins. I'm not sure how to do that though. Do I need to create my own docker container?
- use docker file with secured nginx like this one https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/marvambass/nginx-ssl-secure/ and somehow combine two docker containers or make them communicate? Not sure how to that either.

Could someone experienced please recommend me the best solution?

P.S. I'm not sure how much troubles ec2 is going to give me but I assume its just about opening 443 in a security group.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

After passing few tutorials on Docker I found that the easiest option to follow is number 2. Jenkins docker image declares the entry point in a way that you can easily pass arguments to the jenkins.

Lets say you have your keystore (e.g. self-signed in this example) as jenkins_keystore.jks in the home folder of ubuntu ec2 instance. Here is the example how to generate one:

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias selfsigned -keystore jenkins_keystore.jks -storepass mypassword -keysize 2048
```

Now you can easily configure jenkins to run on https only without creating your own docker image:

```
docker run -v /home/ubuntu:/var/jenkins_home -p 443:8443 jenkins --httpPort=-1 --httpsPort=8443 --httpsKeyStore=/var/jenkins_home/jenkins_keystore.jks --httpsKeyStorePassword=mypassword
```

- `-v /home/ubuntu:/var/jenkins_home` exposes the host home folder to the jenkins docker container
- `-p 443:8443` maps 8443 jenkins port in the container to the 443 port of the host
- `--httpPort=-1 --httpsPort=8443` blocks jenkins http and exposes it with https on port 8443 inside the container
- `--httpsKeyStore=/var/jenkins_home/jenkins_keystore.jks --httpsKeyStorePassword=mypassword` provides your keystore that has been mapped from the host home folder to the container `/var/jenkins_home/` folder.

Answer (score 13):

Like [otognan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3692910), I would also recommend doing #2, but it seems that his answer is outdated.

First of all, use the `jenkins/jenkins:lts` image, as the `jenkins` image is deprecated (see https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins/ )

Now, lets set it up.  You'll need to stop your current jenkins container to free up the ports.

First, you'll need a certificate keystore.  If you don't have one, you could create a self-signed one with

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias selfsigned -keystore jenkins_keystore.jks -storepass mypassword -keysize 4096
```

Next, let's pass the SSL arguments into the jenkins container.  This is the script I use to do so:

```
read -s -p "Keystore Password:" password
echo
sudo cp jenkins_keystore.jks /var/lib/docker/volumes/jenkins_home/_data
docker run -d -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home -v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -p 443:8443 -p 50000:50000 jenkins/jenkins:lts --httpPort=-1 --httpsPort=8443 --httpsKeyStore=/var/jenkins_home/jenkins_keystore.jks --httpsKeyStorePassword=$password
```

- this script prompts the user for the keystore password
- `-v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home` creates a named volume called `jenkins_home`, which happens to exist at `/var/lib/docker/volumes/jenkins_home/_data` by convention.

  - if the directory at `/var/lib/docker/volumes/jenkins_home/_data` does not exist yet, you will need to create the named volume using `docker volume` before copying the keystore.
- `-p 443:8443` maps 8443 jenkins port in the container to the 443 port of the host
- `--httpPort=-1 --httpsPort=8443` blocks http and exposes https on port 8443 inside the container (port 443 outside the container).
- `--httpsKeyStore=/var/jenkins_home/jenkins_keystore.jks --httpsKeyStorePassword=$password` provides your keystore, which exists at `/var/jenkins_home/jenkins_keystore.jks` inside the container ( `/var/lib/docker/volumes/jenkins_home/_data/jenkins_keystore.jks` outside the container).
- `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` is optional, but is the recommended way to allow your jenkins instance to spin up other docker containers.

  - WARNING:  By giving the container access to `/var/run/docker.sock`, it is easy to break out of the containment provided by the container, and gain access to the host machine.  This is obviously a potential security risk.
- `-v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker` is also optional, but allows your jenkins container to be able to run the docker binary.

  - Be aware that, because docker is now dynamically linked, it no longer comes with dependencies, so you may be required to install dependencies in the container.
  - The alternative is to omit `-v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker` and install docker within the jenkins container.  You'll need to ensure that the inner container docker and the outer host docker are the same version, so that communication over `/var/run/docker.sock` is supported.
  - In either case, you may want to use a Dockerfile to create a new Jenkins docker image.
  - Another alternative is to include `-v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker`, but install a statically-linked binary of docker on the host machine.

You should now be able to access the jenkins webportal via https with no port specifier (since port 443 is default for https)

Thanks to [otognan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3692910) for getting me part of the way here.

Comment: If you don't want to use a self-signed certificate, you could try the directions at https://github.com/hughperkins/howto-jenkins-ssl/blob/master/letsencrypt.md .  Note: I haven't tried these.

Answer (score 3):

**Install Self-Signed SSL Certification to Jenkins Container**

I have setup my jenkins in AWS EC2 instance with docker using official jenkins container. I have used docker-compose to build and run jenkins container and here is my docker-compose.yml file

First, you will need certificate keystore. If you already have a certificate keystorke, no need to run below code. So to generate certificate keystroke run

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias selfsigned -keystore jenkins.jks -storepass password -keysize 4096
```

please be careful with volume mapping because i have places my **jenkins.jks** file in **/opt/cert** folder and my jenkins directory is in **/jenkins** foler and inside that jenkins foler i have my **docker-compose.yml** file and **jenkins_home** directory

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins
    container_name: jenkins-docker
    restart: always
    privileged: true
    user: root
    ports:
      - 443:8443
      - 50000:50000
    volumes:
      - ./jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
      - ../opt/cert/jenkins.jks:/var/lib/jenkins/jenkins.jks
    environment:
      JAVA_OPTS: -Duser.timezone=CET
      JENKINS_OPTS: --httpPort=-1 --httpsPort=443 --httpsKeyStore=/var/lib/jenkins/jenkins.jks --httpsKeyStorePassword=password
```

after the all these steps , check your jenkins container is up and running. If so , then you can access your jenkins with browser with simply typing https://public-ip:443

Comment: Very nice answer, but `--httpPort=-1 --httpsPort=443` are ports inside the container, so it must be `--httpsPort=8443` in your case

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old topic but I wanted to share a blog post which covers reverse proxy option in detail: https://itnext.io/setting-up-https-for-jenkins-with-nginx-everything-in-docker-4a118dc29127

Jenkins suggests to setup reverse proxy in documents. It may seem like an extra effort in the first place but it is a general solution for other services related with CI/CD environment as well (i.e. SonarQube).

Answer (score 0):

I would use nginx together with jenkins in the same container, and use supervisord to manage both processes.  Securing different services with builtin tools is a pain; nginx works the same for all services, and is easy to configure.  It is possible, and nicer in some ways, to use docker-compose (was fig) to create two different containers and hook them up with the pretty internal networking that docker provides with links.  The problem is that running pairs of jobs together is still not well supported in cluster managers like marathon.  It's far easier to tell most services to run a single container, rather than to run two containers, but make sure they're on the same host.