# running jenkins on localhost with SSL through Docker

Tags: docker, ssl, jenkins, localhost, port

I want to run jenkins on localhost via docker with 2 conditions.

1. I need port 443
2. it should be `https://` instead of `http://`

I tried everything, but I am still stuck with this issues.

This is the command I am using to run jenkins on port 443:

`docker run -p 443:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v ~/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:lts`

It transfers the port to 443, but does not make it HTTPS.
I have my cert and key from `mkcert` in root folder(`/users/myname/`).   But I do not know how to transfer it to Jenkins configurations.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The [Jenkins initial settings](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/initial-settings/) includes

- `--httpPort=$HTTP_PORT`:  To disable (because you’re using HTTPS), use port -1.
- `--httpsPort=$HTTPS_PORT`: Uses HTTPS protocol on port `$HTTPS_PORT`.

So if you want to run Jenkins with HTTPS, you need:

- to activate an HTTPS port (and map it)
- to pass a self-signed certificate

You have a full [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54432392/6309), run with:

```sh
read -s -p "Keystore Password:" password
echo
sudo cp jenkins_keystore.jks /var/lib/docker/volumes/jenkins_home/_data
```

And:

`docker run -d -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home -v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -p 443:8443 -p 50000:50000 jenkins/jenkins:lts --httpPort=-1 --httpsPort=8443 --httpsKeyStore=/var/jenkins_home/jenkins_keystore.jks --httpsKeyStorePassword=$password`

Comment: I saw that post earlier. it keeps giving me error    " cp: /var/lib/docker/volumes/jenkins_home/_data: No such file or director". I tried the whole internet and couldnt find a solution that fully works..Further i have generated the  cert.pem and key.pem. but i dont know how to use it for my purpose. i want to add them instead of self signed .

Comment: @PreetiSaraswat It supposes you have created first a folder jenkins_home mounted in /var/jenkins_home: running the docker command once will generate the `/var/lib/docker/volumes/jenkins_home/_data` path. Then stop and exit the container. You can do the `sudo cp` command.